# Email , Name are missing in Attribute mapping of AWS Cognito User pool - Sign in with Apple External Identity Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, sign-in-with-apple

I created a Cognito User pool and would like to integrate Sign in with Apple as External Provider.

Mapped Apple details as below

[image]

In the Attribute Mapping  **Email**, **Name** is missing like below
[image]

MFA is enabled(required) and Log in with email is selected, email is a required attribute on pool creation.

For **User pool 1** email, names are missing in Attribute Mapping?

---

Created another user pool with MFA optional and Log in with username selected, email is a required attribute on pool creation.

for this user pool email, the name appears in Attribute Mapping?

**User pool 2** [image]

[image]

[image]

May I know the reason why Email, Name are missing in Attribute mapping in the Case of **User pool1**?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue few days back, try disabling and enabling the **sign in with apple** is what worked for me